# How to create custom middleware that should be invoke for every page click or button click of Blazor

Tags: .net, session, blazor, timeout, middleware

What I want is, for every hit to Blazor actions, it should come to my middleware so that I can check the timeout.

please note:
I did try script function to catch click / key down actions but they are not working correctly,
it makes user log-out even if user clicking randomly..
I can not use Microsoft.Session in Blazor, so can not implement time-out logic on that.
So, If user is clicking any page, or there is any specific class object called, this middleware should be invoked..`

```
`public class SessionTimeoutMiddleware
    {
        private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
        private ATMTreeViewRepository _atmTreeService { get; set; }
        private IServiceProvider _serviceProvider { get; set; }

        public SessionTimeoutMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ATMTreeViewRepository atmTreeService, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _next = next;
            _atmTreeService = atmTreeService;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }
        public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            if (_atmTreeService.sessionTime == null)
            {
                _atmTreeService.sessionTime = DateTime.Now;
            }
            else
            {
                double minutes = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_atmTreeService.sessionTime.Value).TotalMinutes;
                if (minutes > 5)
                {
                    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var _navigationManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();

                        if (_navigationManager != null)
                            _navigationManager.NavigateTo($"{_navigationManager.BaseUri}");
                    }                    
                }
                else
                {
                    _atmTreeService.sessionTime = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
            await _next(httpContext);
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Blazor apps only use middleware on launch. You might make this work (a little) better with .net 8. But basically, rethink what you want/need here.

Comment: Am I reading this correctly: Do you want to run a bit of code whenever the user clicks a button or enters some data in an input, or do you want to run a bit of code when they navigate?

Comment: yes detecting navigation can also resolve it

Answer (score 0):

You can implement this in the MainLayout to check all navigation events.  It registers a handler for the Navigation Manager before navigation event.  It just writes a line to the Output window to demo how to do it.

```cs
@using System.Diagnostics;
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@implements IDisposable

<PageTitle>SO76998619</PageTitle>
<div class="page">
    <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>

    <main>
        <div class="top-row px-4">
            <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/" target="_blank">About</a>
        </div>

        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>

@code {
    private IDisposable? _disposable;
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _disposable = this.NavManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler(OnBeforeNavigateAsync);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private ValueTask OnBeforeNavigateAsync(LocationChangingContext context)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Just checking before navigating");
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;   
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _disposable?.Dispose();
    }
}
```

If you want to check on each UI event you need to create a base component that implements a different `IHandleEvent` handler.

Here's a demo component that again just currently logs to Output.

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace SO76998619.Shared
{
    public class MyComponentBase : ComponentBase, IHandleEvent
    {
        async Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(EventCallbackWorkItem item, object? obj)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Do a quick check before executing UI Event");

            var uiTask = item.InvokeAsync(obj);

            await this.CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(uiTask);

            this.StateHasChanged();
        }

        protected async Task<bool> CheckIfShouldRunStateHasChanged(Task task)
        {
            var isCompleted = task.IsCompleted || task.IsCanceled;

            if (!isCompleted)
            {
                this.StateHasChanged();
                await task;
                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

In the base template you would need t set the inheritance on pages such as `NavMenu` and all your normal route pages.

It's not particularly elegant!